Issues with custom-nginx.conf in AWS Elastic Beanstalk not working
My server has been under this type of attack every day for about 1 year and as far as I have researched, it is a similar type of attack on multiple servers.
Django's own security is not fully effective against this attack, it only causes the other side to get a 400 error, but since the attack is ongoing, the system temporarily shuts down and then reboots. Probably because I'm using aws elastic beanstalk, the system gets itself up and running again. So I'm trying to solve this problem with nginx but I haven't succeeded yet.
 172.31.44.14 - - [21/Sep/2024:01:43:13 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 400 154 "-" "Mozilla/5.0" "35.216.141.220"
172.31.44.14 - - [21/Sep/2024:01:45:30 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 400 154 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/60.0.3112.113 Safari/537.36" "45.156.129.46"
172.31.26.204 - - [21/Sep/2024:01:46:39 +0000] "GET /.well-known/acme-challenge/0JCWGV2T84AUO8ZXX8HLI-GW7EEZNV9G HTTP/1.1" 301 5 "-" "Cpanel-HTTP-Client/1.0" "94.199.206.16"
172.31.26.204 - - [21/Sep/2024:01:46:40 +0000] "GET /.well-known/acme-challenge/0JCWGV2T84AUO8ZXX8HLI-GW7EEZNV9G HTTP/1.1" 200 6699 "-" "Cpanel-HTTP-Client/1.0" "94.199.206.16"
172.31.26.204 - - [21/Sep/2024:01:59:04 +0000] "GET /.env HTTP/1.1" 400 154 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux armv7l) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Raspbian Chromium/72.0.3626.121 Chrome/72.0.3626.121 Safari/537.36" "91.92.243.155"
172.31.44.14 - - [21/Sep/2024:02:11:07 +0000] "POST /cgi-bin/.%2e/.%2e/.%2e/.%2e/.%2e/.%2e/.%2e/.%2e/.%2e/.%2e/bin/sh HTTP/1.1" 400 157 "-" "-" "-"
172.31.44.14 - - [21/Sep/2024:02:11:07 +0000] "POST /cgi-bin/%%32%65%%32%65/%%32%65%%32%65/%%32%65%%32%65/%%32%65%%32%65/%%32%65%%32%65/%%32%65%%32%65/%%32%65%%32%65/bin/sh HTTP/1.1" 400 157 "-" "-" "-"
172.31.44.14 - - [21/Sep/2024:02:11:07 +0000] "POST /hello.world?%ADd+allow_url_include%3d1+%ADd+auto_prepend_file%3dphp://input HTTP/1.1" 400 154 "-" "Custom-AsyncHttpClient" "47.251.99.88"
172.31.44.14 - - [21/Sep/2024:02:11:07 +0000] "GET /vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Util/PHP/eval-stdin.php HTTP/1.1" 400 154 "-" "Custom-AsyncHttpClient" "47.251.99.88"
172.31.44.14 - - [21/Sep/2024:02:11:09 +0000] "GET /vendor/phpunit/phpunit/Util/PHP/eval-stdin.php HTTP/1.1" 400 154 "-" "Custom-AsyncHttpClient" "47.251.99.88"
172.31.44.14 - - [21/Sep/2024:02:11:10 +0000] "GET /vendor/phpunit/src/Util/PHP/eval-stdin.php HTTP/1.1" 400 154 "-" "Custom-AsyncHttpClient" "47.251.99.88"
172.31.44.14 - - [21/Sep/2024:02:11:10 +0000] "GET /vendor/phpunit/Util/PHP/eval-stdin.php HTTP/1.1" 400 154 "-" "Custom-AsyncHttpClient" "47.251.99.88"
172.31.44.14 - - [21/Sep/2024:02:11:10 +0000] "GET /vendor/phpunit/phpunit/LICENSE/eval-stdin.php HTTP/1.1" 400 154 "-" "Custom-AsyncHttpClient" "47.251.99.88"
172.31.44.14 - - [21/Sep/2024:02:11:11 +0000] "GET /vendor/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Util/PHP/eval-stdin.php HTTP/1.1" 400 154 "-" "Custom-AsyncHttpClient" "47.251.99.88"
172.31.44.14 - - [21/Sep/2024:02:11:12 +0000] "GET /phpunit/phpunit/src/Util/PHP/eval-stdin.php HTTP/1.1" 400 154 "-" "Custom-AsyncHttpClient" "47.251.99.88"
172.31.44.14 - - [21/Sep/2024:02:11:13 +0000] "GET /phpunit/phpunit/Util/PHP/eval-stdin.php HTTP/1.1" 400 154 "-" "Custom-AsyncHttpClient" "47.251.99.88"
172.31.44.14 - - [21/Sep/2024:02:11:17 +0000] "GET /phpunit/src/Util/PHP/eval-stdin.php HTTP/1.1" 400 154 "-" "Custom-AsyncHttpClient" "47.251.99.88"
172.31.44.14 - - [21/Sep/2024:02:11:18 +0000] "GET /phpunit/Util/PHP/eval-stdin.php HTTP/1.1" 400 154 "-" "Custom-AsyncHttpClient" "47.251.99.88"
172.31.44.14 - - [21/Sep/2024:02:11:19 +0000] "GET /lib/phpunit/phpunit/src/Util/PHP/eval-stdin.php HTTP/1.1" 400 154 "-" "Custom-AsyncHttpClient" "47.251.99.88"
172.31.44.14 - - [21/Sep/2024:02:11:19 +0000] "GET /lib/phpunit/phpunit/Util/PHP/eval-stdin.php HTTP/1.1" 400 154 "-" "Custom-AsyncHttpClient" "47.251.99.88"
172.31.44.14 - - [21/Sep/2024:02:11:21 +0000] "GET /lib/phpunit/src/Util/PHP/eval-stdin.php HTTP/1.1" 400 154 "-" "Custom-AsyncHttpClient" "47.251.99.88"
172.31.44.14 - - [21/Sep/2024:02:11:21 +0000] "GET /lib/phpunit/Util/PHP/eval-stdin.php HTTP/1.1" 400 154 "-" "Custom-AsyncHttpClient" "47.251.99.88"
172.31.44.14 - - [21/Sep/2024:02:11:21 +0000] "GET /lib/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Util/PHP/eval-stdin.php HTTP/1.1" 400 154 "-" "Custom-AsyncHttpClient" "47.251.99.88"
172.31.44.14 - - [21/Sep/2024:02:11:22 +0000] "GET /laravel/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Util/PHP/eval-stdin.php HTTP/1.1" 400 154 "-" "Custom-AsyncHttpClient" "47.251.99.88"
172.31.44.14 - - [21/Sep/2024:02:11:22 +0000] "GET /www/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Util/PHP/eval-stdin.php HTTP/1.1" 400 154 "-" "Custom-AsyncHttpClient" "47.251.99.88"
172.31.44.14 - - [21/Sep/2024:02:11:23 +0000] "GET /ws/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Util/PHP/eval-stdin.php HTTP/1.1" 400 154 "-" "Custom-AsyncHttpClient" "47.251.99.88"
172.31.44.14 - - [21/Sep/2024:02:11:24 +0000] "GET /yii/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Util/PHP/eval-stdin.php HTTP/1.1" 400 154 "-" "Custom-AsyncHttpClient" "47.251.99.88"
172.31.44.14 - - [21/Sep/2024:02:11:24 +0000] "GET /zend/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Util/PHP/eval-stdin.php HTTP/1.1" 400 154 "-" "Custom-AsyncHttpClient" "47.251.99.88"
172.31.44.14 - - [21/Sep/2024:02:11:24 +0000] "GET /ws/ec/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Util/PHP/eval-stdin.php HTTP/1.1" 400 154 "-" "Custom-AsyncHttpClient" "47.251.99.88"
172.31.44.14 - - [21/Sep/2024:02:11:24 +0000] "GET /V2/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Util/PHP/eval-stdin.php HTTP/1.1" 400 154 "-" "Custom-AsyncHttpClient" "47.251.99.88"
172.31.44.14 - - [21/Sep/2024:02:11:28 +0000] "GET /tests/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Util/PHP/eval-stdin.php HTTP/1.1" 400 154 "-" "Custom-AsyncHttpClient" "47.251.99.88"
172.31.44.14 - - [21/Sep/2024:02:11:28 +0000] "GET /test/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Util/PHP/eval-stdin.php HTTP/1.1" 400 154 "-" "Custom-AsyncHttpClient" "47.251.99.88"
172.31.44.14 - - [21/Sep/2024:02:11:28 +0000] "GET /testing/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Util/PHP/eval-stdin.php HTTP/1.1" 400 154 "-" "Custom-AsyncHttpClient" "47.251.99.88"
172.31.44.14 - - [21/Sep/2024:02:11:29 +0000] "GET /api/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Util/PHP/eval-stdin.php HTTP/1.1" 400 154 "-" "Custom-AsyncHttpClient" "47.251.99.88"
172.31.44.14 - - [21/Sep/2024:02:11:29 +0000] "GET /demo/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Util/PHP/eval-stdin.php HTTP/1.1" 400 154 "-" "Custom-AsyncHttpClient" "47.251.99.88"
172.31.44.14 - - [21/Sep/2024:02:11:29 +0000] "GET /cms/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Util/PHP/eval-stdin.php HTTP/1.1" 400 154 "-" "Custom-AsyncHttpClient" "47.251.99.88"
172.31.44.14 - - [21/Sep/2024:02:11:31 +0000] "GET /crm/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Util/PHP/eval-stdin.php HTTP/1.1" 400 154 "-" "Custom-AsyncHttpClient" "47.251.99.88"
172.31.44.14 - - [21/Sep/2024:02:11:32 +0000] "GET /admin/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Util/PHP/eval-stdin.php HTTP/1.1" 400 154 "-" "Custom-AsyncHttpClient" "47.251.99.88"
172.31.44.14 - - [21/Sep/2024:02:11:32 +0000] "GET /backup/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Util/PHP/eval-stdin.php HTTP/1.1" 400 154 "-" "Custom-AsyncHttpClient" "47.251.99.88"
172.31.44.14 - - [21/Sep/2024:02:11:33 +0000] "GET /blog/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Util/PHP/eval-stdin.php HTTP/1.1" 400 154 "-" "Custom-AsyncHttpClient" "47.251.99.88"
172.31.44.14 - - [21/Sep/2024:02:11:34 +0000] "GET /workspace/drupal/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Util/PHP/eval-stdin.php HTTP/1.1" 400 154 "-" "Custom-AsyncHttpClient" "47.251.99.88"
172.31.44.14 - - [21/Sep/2024:02:11:34 +0000] "GET /panel/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Util/PHP/eval-stdin.php HTTP/1.1" 400 154 "-" "Custom-AsyncHttpClient" "47.251.99.88"
172.31.44.14 - - [21/Sep/2024:02:11:34 +0000] "GET /public/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Util/PHP/eval-stdin.php HTTP/1.1" 400 154 "-" "Custom-AsyncHttpClient" "47.251.99.88"
172.31.44.14 - - [21/Sep/2024:02:11:35 +0000] "GET /apps/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Util/PHP/eval-stdin.php HTTP/1.1" 400 154 "-" "Custom-AsyncHttpClient" "47.251.99.88"
172.31.44.14 - - [21/Sep/2024:02:11:35 +0000] "GET /app/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Util/PHP/eval-stdin.php HTTP/1.1" 400 154 "-" "Custom-AsyncHttpClient" "47.251.99.88"


I'm working with AWS Elastic Beanstalk and have implemented a custom custom-nginx.conf configuration to enhance security settings of my application. The configuration includes user agent blocking, proxy settings, directory traversal protection, and more. After deploying with eb deploy, the deployment completes without errors, but it doesnt the security settings are not being enforced as expected.
What exactly could I be doing wrong?

Here's the configuration I'm considering:
.ebextensions > custom-nginx.config
files:
  "/etc/nginx/conf.d/custom.conf":
    mode: "000644"
    owner: root
    group: root
    content: |
      # User Agent blocking and other security rules
      map $http_user_agent $blocked_user_agent {
          default 0;
          "~*curl" 1;
          "~*wget" 1;
          "~*bot" 1;
          "~*spider" 1;
          "~*crawl" 1;
          "~*Custom-AsyncHttpClient" 1;
          "~*Cpanel-HTTP-Client/1.0" 1;
          "~*Go-http-client/1.1" 1;
      }

      server {
          listen 80;

          # Proxy buffering settings
          proxy_buffering off;
          proxy_buffers 16 16k;
          proxy_buffer_size 32k;

          # Prevent directory traversal attacks
          location ~* "/\.\./" {
              deny all;
          }

          # Block specific file extensions
          location ~* \.(php|env|ini|log|sql|conf|bak|old|sh|yml|aspx|ext)$ {
              return 403;
          }

          # Block WordPress access
          location ~* /(wp-admin|wp-login|wp-content|wp-includes)/ {
              return 403;
          }

          # Block specific HTTP methods
          if ($request_method ~* (HEAD|TRACE)) {
              return 403;
          }

          # Block malicious User-Agents
          if ($blocked_user_agent) {
              return 403;
          }

          # Timeout settings
          client_body_timeout 10s;
          client_header_timeout 10s;
          keepalive_timeout 5s 5s;
          send_timeout 10s;
      }

container_commands:
  reload_nginx:
    command: "service nginx restart"


  



